# Optimization with Dependent Constraints

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

In the general theory of constrained optimization, is it possible to pose a minimization problem subject to some constraints that are dependent?

For example, suppose we aim to minimize an objective function $\mathscr F(x,y,z)$, for the design parameters $x$, $y$, and $z$, such that $z=x^2+y^2$. Is it correct to have such constraint, theoretically?

**EDIT**
$z=x^2+y^2$

Comment: Yes you can write that. Or "subject to the constraint $z^2=x^2+y^2$"

Comment: Thank you, but I am asking if the problem is correctly posed from the mathematical point of view and can be solved, rather than how it is written.

Comment: Of course, completely standard in constrained optimization

Comment: One thing that works quite frequently is to, in the above, set $z=\pm \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ (breaking this up into two cases). And then optimizing the two variable function $\mathscr F(x,y,\pm \sqrt{x^2+y^2})$. This doesn't work for all functions, but it will for the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Cade Reinberger said in a comment, you can do this by expressing your constraint as $z=z(x,y)$ (might work with any of the variables, if at all)
and then minimising the resulting function $F(x,y)=\mathscr F(x,y,z(x,y))$ by solving $\nabla F(x,y)=\mathbf 0$.

Alternatively, you can express your constraint as $g(x,y,z)=0$ and solve the system
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
\nabla\mathscr F(x,y,z)&=\lambda\nabla g(x,y,z) \\
g(x,y,z)&=0
\end{align}
\right.
.$$
If you'd like some explanation of this method, it's called the method of Lagrange multipliers, and it comes from the way the contours of the functions behave at critical points.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I tried to apply the first method that you mentioned, but only keeping $z$ as an unknown parameter (to solve for it) and not expressing it in terms of $x$ and $y$. My objective is to obtain a linear system from $\nabla \mathscr F(x,y,z)=\mathbf0 $ that can be easily solved, which is possible (if I do so) given the derivatives I obtain.  
However, I am obtaining wrong results because by checking the condition  $z=x^2+y^2$, I find that is not satisfied. Could you tell if that is because the procedure of solving for the three parameter is not correct?

Comment: It sounds like your issue is that you're finding *unconstrained* critical points and hoping that they satisfy the constraint, but your constraint actually changes the critical points, so you cannot just try and match them up.

Comment: Could you please clarify your point a little bit because I don't have background on optimization and not familiar with some terms (like _critical points_)? I'm trying to solve this for an engineering problem.

Are you saying that I cannot satisfy the constraint $z=x^2+y^2$ if I solve for $x$, $y$, and $z$ all together?

Comment: Critical points are points where a function might have an extremum (maximum or minimum). If you have a particular \mathscr F I can show you what I mean

Comment: OK, but kindly I still didn't receive an answer on whether the procedure is correct or not since the constraint $z=x^2+y^2$ is not satisfied.

Comment: Oh, sorry. No, that will only work for an unconstrained optimisation problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You saved me hours of trying to debug my algorithm and understand what's wrong with the math.
Just to confirm that I'm understanding correctly: (I'm being very precise) Since I'm aiming to minimize a function $\scr F(x,y)$ for the unknown parameters $x$ and $y$ and imposing the constraint $z=x^2+y^2$, it is incorrect to pose the problem like I'm minimizing $\scr F(x,y,z)$ for $x$, $y$, and $z$ all together subject to $z=x^2+y^2$. Could you please affirm this statement, or give me a better mathematical explanation to explain the invalidity of what I tried to do?

Comment: Your statement is correct